# Docker service showing no such image when trying to upgrade service

Tags: docker

First of all sorry if I have a bad english.

We have a service that was being upgraded until 26 / September / 2022, via portainer or via terminal on Docker. It was on gitlab registry.

We did not make any changes but we are not able to upgrade it anymore!

How can we debug why this message is appearing?
No such image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxx/xxx/api:1.1.18@sha256:xxxx

Some additional informations:

-We are using docker login before trying to do the service update.

-We can do docker pull registry.gitlab.com/etc/etc (the version)

The problem only occurs when we try to upgrade it as a service.

There is some kind of debug on the service upgrade that can provide some additional information like firewall is blocking or something like this?

```
docker service update nameofservice
nameofservice
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: preparing [=================================>                 ] 

Until return the error 'no such image'!
```

I am pretty sure the image exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are experiencing the same problem, check if you have more nodes, phisical machines or vms running connected to your docker node (docker node ls).

If that is your case, run docker pull gitlabaddressetcetc on the other nodes and check if everything is fine.

I found the message 'No space left on device', so I runned 'df -h' but a lot of space are available for the VM. Anyway I decided to run 'docker prune -f' to see what happens:

So running the 'docker system prune -f' seems to solved my problem, and everything is fine now.

After that I just needed to change the version of the portainer to a invalid one before trying again.